# Code: 0xC0029151. The process exit code was "-1073740791" while the expected was "0"

Tags: sql-server, teradata, sql-job, executeprocesstask

I'm trying to load multiple tables from SQL server to Teradata by launching Fastload through .bat files on Execute Process tasks one by one. If I run the batch files directly, it works. I run the SSIS package, it works. I run the package from Integration services, it works. This error occurs only when running it through a job.

I have checked the Folder permissions and SQLSERVERAGENT & MSSQLSERVER have been given full control. The Proxy used is my account. I am an admin on the both the Server as well as the SQL Server. The Fastload files were created through 64-bit OLELoad, though I have tried it through both 32 and 64 bit Execution Options, either way it fails. All the other packages created on the same solution go through without a hitch on the same job, only difference : none of the other packages have an execute process task.

Weirdly enough, it completes loading the table on the first task and then fails at the first task instead of moving to the second one. I have checked the table on Teradata and the row count matches and data seems good. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what does the "-1073740791" in the error message mean? I don't understand where it is getting that number from.

Comment: The bat file, @HarryS . When an application closes, it returns something call an exit code; normally code `0` means "Closed without error", and anything else means that the application closed due to an unexpected reason, such as an error.

Comment: As a workaround, I've set 'FailTaskReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue' to 'False' on the tasks as the tables seem to be loading. Not sure if this will cause any issue in future though.

Comment: Hey @Larnu, thanks for your response.. I get the exit code part. What I'm wondering is where it gets the value 'minus billion' from.

Comment: `-1073740791` is the specific exit code that was received, @HarryS, which likely related to an error code. You've not shared *any* code here, so what application *that* error code comes from, or what it represents we have no idea. Exit codes are normally far more useful to the application developer, rather than the user (as normally the User wouldn't be consuming said exit codes).

Comment: You might have the SQL Agent proxy account configured to use your admin account but that doesn't mean it's also loading your user profile - and environment variables. Do you have `FLOADLIB` configured in your account's environment variables, or the Teradata bin folder in your `PATH`? Try defining them in the system environment variables instead.

Comment: The 0xC0029151 essentially just says SSIS thinks there was an error. The -107340791 is decimal equivalent of 0xC0000409 which is normally "Stack Buffer Overrun". Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: Sorry I think my comment deviated my question from the main issue. "it completes loading the table on the first task and then fails at the first task instead of moving to the second one. I have checked the table on Teradata and the row count matches and data seems good." How do I make the resolve this error so it moves to the next task. The code is good and works manually on bat files, through Integration Services as well. Only on the job it fails